# Array assignment in awk on ksh environment

Tags: awk, ksh

One of my awk script works well in bash shell environment, but I found it doesn't on ksh (AIX).

```
awk: Cannot make an assignment to j. It is an array name.
```

I am not good at awk scripting and it would be helpful to show me the wrong part so that I could run it on ksh without any issue.
I also wonder if I can define the shell kinds such as bash,ksh and csh at the head of the awk script. Is there any way of it?

INPUT & Full awk script

```
Job ID    : 56
Status    : Done - 1 object completed

ID     Tablename                               Status         Time         Total Rows %Comp Total Time  
------ --------------------------------------- -------------- ------------ ---------- ----- ------------
1      "TEST"."TEST"."TEST"                    In Good                 N/A    1708219   100         1:26


BEGIN {
    count = 0
    job_id = 0
    status = 0
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}

/^Job ID/ {
    job_id = $4 
    a[job_id] = job_id "#-1#no_data#no_data#no_data#-1#-1#no_data"
    count++
}

/^Status/ {
   match($0,/[0-9]+/)
   status = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
   temp = a[job_id]
   delete a[job_id]
   a[job_id] = temp "#" status
}

/^[0-9]/ {
    delete a[job_id]
    string = job_id
    step_skip = 0
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (i == 4 || (i == 5 && step_skip == 1)) {
            continue
        } else if (i == 2) {
            gsub(/"/, "", $i);
            gsub(/\./, "#", $i);
            string = string "#" $i
        } else if (i == 3){
            if (match($i, /^Out/)) {
                string = string "#" $i " " $(i+1)
                step_skip = 1
           } else if (match($i, /^In/)) {
                string = string "#" $i " " $(i+1)
                step_skip = 1
            } else if (match($i, /^Skipped/)) {
                string = string "#" $i "#-1#-1#no_data"
                break
            } else {
                string = string "#" $i
            }
        } else if (i == 6 || (i == 7 && step_skip == 1)) {
            if (match($i, /:/)) {
                string = string "#-1#" $i 
            } else {
                string = string "#" $i
            }
        }else {
            string = string "#" $i
        }
    }
    a[job_id, $1] = string "#" status

}

END {

    for (j in a) {
        if (j in a) {
            print a[j]
        }

        temp = a[j]

        if (PROCINFO["temp"] == "array") {
            for (k in j) {
                print a[j, k]
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the code you've shared which causes the error? It doesn't try to assign to j, so it doesn't seem likely. If you remove the `END` block, does the error disappear?

Comment: awk has nothing to do with your shell and vice-versa. Post a minimal, complete awk script that demonstrates the problem so we can help you debug it.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your comment. Pasted a full script.

Comment: `for (k in j) {` seems wrong, you're treating `j` as an array, where it isn't.

Comment: You didn't accept the answer of @EdMorton. Can you explain what is unclear for you ?

Comment: With the advice, I have been trying to fix the issue. Definitely, I will accept the Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk has nothing to do with your shell and vice-versa. You're experiencing a problem due to a bug in your code being exposed while running different versions of awk, not calling awk from different versions of shell.

In some awks such as the default BSD awk on Mac OS `for (k in j)` being present in the code, even in a leg that can't be reached as in your case, is enough for awk to identify `j` as being an array since you're using an array operation `in` on it so then when awk encounters you treating `j` as a scalar elsewhere in your code (`for (j in a)`) awk tells you you can't do that because `j` is an array.

You have other issues in your code such as using gawk-only constructs like `PROCINFO[]` when you aren't running gawk and you're mixing up pseudo-multi-deimensional arrays indexing syntax (`a[i,j]`) with tests for arrays that could only have been created using gawks arrays-of-arrays syntax (`a[i][j]`) and doing things like `for (j in a) { if (j in a) {` where the `if` can't possible fail and also `temp = a[j]; if (PROCINFO["temp"] == "array")` where `temp` can't possibly be an array or the assignment would have failed. Feel free to post new questions if you'd like help with those or other aspects of your code.

Comment: Great explanation and helpful for resolving the issue !